# How do I find the max, next highest value, and return other cell contents?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1422002/excel.PNG]

I would like to find the max value in column C and return the associated "AM" unit (A3,A16,A29) in E5.

Then, I would like to find the next highest value in column C and return the associated "AM" unit (A3,A16,A29) in F5.

I am not able to post the image of the table, but I have included a link to the Dropbox file.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: No successful attempts.  VLOOKUP doesn't work for me and I do not know how to return another cell related to the max or next highest value.  I'm still searching for an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Using a helper column would make things much simpler, if that's okay with you. And you have `LARGE` which can take the 2nd highest, or 3th highest, or any nth highest as long as there are enough values.

Comment: what is in E5 and F5 ? what is the "AM" value?

Comment: E5 and F5 are cell references.  The "AM" value can be found in the attached file.  They are names attached to vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't answer whether or not you're okay with using a helper column, but that's how I'd do it:

In column D, you can put something like this:

```
=MAX(C5:C13)
```

In cell D3, and `=MAX(C18:C26)` in D16 and so on.

Then in E5, you can use that formula:

```
=INDEX($A:$A, MAX(IF(LARGE($D:$D,1)=$D:$D,ROW($D:$D))))
```

In F5:

```
=INDEX($A:$A, MAX(IF(LARGE($D:$D,2)=$D:$D,ROW($D:$D))))
```

Note that `=MAX()` is equivalent to `=LARGE( ,1)` so that the first formula could also be written as `=INDEX($A:$A, MAX(IF(MAX($D:$D)=$D:$D,ROW($D:$D))))`

Now, these are array formulae, so that you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of the conventional <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make them work properly.

Also, one last note, you can change the ranges `$A:$A` and `$D:$D` to something like `$A3:$A40` and `$D3:$D40` to make the formula work faster, since there's less cells to treat.

Comment: Thank you, Jerry!  A helper column is acceptable.  I am getting #NUM1 return when using the second formula.

Comment: @RCK I'm not sure how that's happening o.o Um, you usually get #NUM! when there's a value bigger than what excel can represent...

Comment: Thank you again, Jerry.  I was able to redesign the sheet and use INDEX/MATCH to find my solutions.